# VC++ / Dev-C++: How to include an DLL?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, dll, dev-c++

I have written an DLL in Delphi which exports functions. I would like to use these functions in a C++ program without using dynamic Linking (LoadLibrary() API-Call).

The "import" declaration would be

```
extern "C" int __stdcall getVersionNumber();
```

I mainly use Bloodshed Dev-C++ which creates Windows Executables. But I do not know how to tell the compiler that it should import the function "getVersionNumber" from "STATMONDLL32.dll".

After I spent many hours by googling the problem, without any result (there was only weird stuff written about .a files and .lib files, which I do not have compiled by Delphi...) I have also installed VC++, but even there, I could not find a way to tell the compiler to use a specific DLL.

I have created a DEF file for this DLL - how can I tell Dev-C++ and/or VC++ to use it? (Dev-C++ prefered)

// Edit: Delphi is creating UNDECORATED symbols. The symbol is exactly "getVersionNumber".

I have created following DEF file with an alias for decoration:

```
LIBRARY   STATMONDLL32
EXPORTS
  getVersionNumberA = _getVersionNumberA@0
```

I have created a *.lib file with VC++ "lib.exe":

```
lib.exe /DEF:StatMonDll32.def /OUT:StatMonDll32.lib
```

I have included the lib in VC++ linker settings.

But VC++ tells me that it cannot resolve the external symbol _getVersionNumberA@0 ! Please help!

// Edit: I have uploaded the DLL here: http://www.viathinksoft.de/temp/StatMonDll32.dll . Can you access the symbol getVersionNumberA with VC++ ? I am searching for a solution since 6 days now :'-(

Best regards

Daniel Marschall

Comment: [Don't use Dev-C++.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dev-c%2b%2b/info)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic linking, it should work something along the lines of:

```
extern "C" typedef int (__stdcall *pfnadd)(int a, int b);
extern "C" typedef int (__stdcall *pfngetversion)(void);
HMODULE mod = LoadLibraryA("mydll.dll");
pfnadd add = (pfnadd)GetProcAddress(mod, "Add");
pfngetversion getVersionNumberA =
       (pfngetversion)GetProcAddress(mod, "getVersionNumberA");
```

and then you can just call using the function pointer:

```
add(1, 2);
std::cout << getVersionNumberA();
```

Although, it seems like your question has bits and pieces of two different functions!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know that I can use dynamic linking, but I would like doing it the static way, like e.g. the WinAPI DLLs are linked. In my post I was talking about different functions for example, but I used only 1 name in my test. I wonder why nobody knows an answer for this simple question. I just want to static link the undecorated function name. (Note: If the name were decorated by a "@0", it would work (tested). But as a matter of fact, Delphi creates undecorated symbols).

Comment: @Daniel: Sorry, I missed the line at the beginning of your question where you said "without `LoadLibrary`".  You need to create a static import library matching the DLL.  cygwin provides good tools for this (that explains the .a files you learned about with google), MSVC++ less so, and I have no idea for Dev-C++.

Comment: I am not sure what a "static import library" is. Didn't I already create it with "lib.exe" which produced a *.lib file out of my *.def file?

Comment: @Daniel: I don't know what options you used to `lib.exe`, but you got them wrong if it still isn't linking.

Comment: I did it with this command: "lib.exe /DEF:StatMonDll32.def /OUT:StatMonDll32.lib" . The lib file is created (and I have included it in VC++ linker settings). The problem is that the DLL has the undecorated symbol "getVersionNumberA" and VC++ wants to access "_getVersionNumberA@0" (because stdcall). I assume the ALIAS did not work. I have looked inside the LIB file with a hex-editor and have seen "_getVersionNumberA" instead of "_getVersionNumberA@0". I assume "@0" is accidently interpreted as ordinal value in the DEF file... I have nearly tried every combination.

Comment: I have uploaded the DLL here: http://www.viathinksoft.de/temp/StatMonDll32.dll . Can you access the symbol getVersionNumberA with VC++ ? I am searching for a solution since 6 days now :'-(